# Function like keyword in return statement before loop in DRF APIView permission

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hey guys I am having a hard time understanding the following return statement code in django drf APIView source code:

```
def get_permissions(self):
        """
        Instantiates and returns the list of permissions that this view requires.
        """
        return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]
```

I understand that **permission** is the key iterating through **permission_classes** but what on earth is the **permission()** doing here

Comment: In an unusual move from the comments, they actually tell you what is happening. It could be that each `permission` is a class, so `permission()` instantiates that class.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback mate. After you pointed it out I now understand that it is instantiating but no idea what its instantiating. There is no sign of a permission class in the APIView source code.